# Java NumberFormatException Error String to Float

Tags: java, numberformatexception

Taking in a list of strings and converting them to a float and storing the values. I get this error when hitting the second value I want to store. Below is the code and the text file I'm reading from:

```
    public static void readCities() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Luke/workspace/Traveling Sales Person/Destinations/11PointDFSBFS.tsp"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    String contents = sb.toString();
    String[] parts = contents.split("NODE_COORD_SECTION");//splits into locations
    String[] locations = parts[1].split(" ");
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < locations.length; i++) {
        cities[counter] = new City(Float.parseFloat(locations[i+1]), Float.parseFloat(locations[i+2]));
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Code error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "63.860370
2
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
    at TSP.readCities(TSP.java:132)
    at TSP.main(TSP.java:28)
```

Comment: Your number string has at least a new line in it (\n), which can't be parsed to a Float. Depending on 11PointDFSBFS.tsp maybe also a space, but since you didn't post the content it's more of a guessing

Comment: You should show us the content of the file.

Comment: Please try to construct and provide a [mcve] which reproduces the error next time - that would've clearly shown you the error, and, if it didn't, it would've led to a question that's much more useful to you as well as the rest of us.

Comment: I suspect there may be too many significant digits in that number. Can you try converting to double instead?

Comment: @SeeSharp `parseFloat` shouldn't have any problem with too many digits after the decimal point, at worst it should just ignore them.

Comment: You forgot to include the text file that you are reading. But you seem to read it including all line breaks, and you never clean out those line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

As all the commenters already said: Without the actual data it's more or less guessing, what is the problem, but with your code and the error-message some things can be said already, what you should do independly:

You read in all the lines and put them into a `StringBuilder` including a new line-break. Later on you do splits, but you never remove this line-break, so it is going to end up in the data you try to parse as float. This will lead to a parsing error, because spaces and other whitespaces are not removed. The easiest way to do this without changing too much in your code is by trimming the values:

```
cities[counter] = new City(Float.parseFloat(locations[i+1].trim()), Float.parseFloat(locations[i+2],trim()));
```

BTW: What's the reason for creating a new variable `counter` that is essentially `i-1` and using `i+1` and `i+2` later on? Makes reading your code a bit harder, because you expect some additional logic where entries are skipped which isn't there.

According to the error-message the problem is a leading quotation mark and a newline. You can't say if that error occurred for the first or the second of the two values that are parsed and without the original line(s) of the input file it's hard to say, what is going on, but maybe I gave you enough hints to allow you to progress with your code.

If not we need more informations, especially the line(s) that produce this error, so analysing your code becomes possible.